# Dryer won't start. Uses a 4 prong 240v outlet where hot/ground is 120v but hot/neutral is 50v. What's wrong?

Tags: receptacle, dryer, appliances, 240v

I recently had a dryer hooked up to this outlet and it ran for 2 years without problem. I recently got a new (to me) Kenmore 400-series dryer that was serviced a month ago and was in perfect condition, though it traveled from 2 states away and was jostled a bit. The new dryer will not start, but I can hear the timer motor ticking when it's plugged in.

I used a multimeter to check the timer, the start switch, and the door switch. All of them were ok (according to what I was seeing from a YouTube tutorial by theapplianceman). I checked the cord. It's fine.

I checked the outlet. H1-H2 gives me 240v. H1-G and H2-G gives me 120v. H1-N and H2-N gives me around 50v.

I don't know what this means. Is this why the dryer won't start? Is it even an issue?

Comment: What voltage do you get N-G?

Comment: N-G measures at 0.1v... fluctuating (if I wiggle the probes) up to 0.7v.

Comment: Also, I just went and measured again to be sure, and I'm still getting 240v H-H, 120v H-G, but now I'm getting only 10v H-N.

Comment: With the dryer unplugged what readings do you get from the receptacle?

Comment: Those are the readings with the dryer unplugged.

Comment: Your neutral is loose either in the receptacle or at the panel. The dryer (at least the new one) requires current through the neutral to operate certain systems.

Comment: Lucky you.  If this had been a 3-wire connection, your loose neutral would have placed 120V on the steel chassis of the dryer and electrocuted anyone who touched it and anything grounded (like the chassis of the *washer right next to it*).   **And people say this never happens.**  Anytime you see an answer on SE that says 3-prong dryer-range hookups are OK  because neutrals don't fail -- link this question.

Comment: Ok, so I just took the receptacle cover off and saw this: There is a regular white/black/bare wire going into the 4 prong receptacle, with white going to H1, black going to H2, and bare going to ground. There is no wire hooked up to the N slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's an open neutral.

The neutral wire has lost connection somewhere.

You are getting indeterminate readings because you are using a common digital multimeter (DVM).  Those have very high input impedance - which is normally a desired feature in a meter.  However on a long run of parallel wires, if a floating wire is near a live one, it will pick up a "ghost voltage" by capacitive coupling or induction.  It doesn't exist in any usable amount of current (paying out 500' of wire under a high-tension line won't get you anything), but these meters are so sensitive they will pick it up as a varying voltage somewhere between 0 and the line voltage of the adjacent wire(s).  It's common for it to drift around, that's a sure sign actually.

So that tells you that your neutral break is probably not right at the receptacle.

---

As a sidebar, 3-prong (groundless) NEMA 10 type connectors are still allowed for dryers and ranges. These omit ground, and ground the chassis of the machine *to neutral*. The logic is that these appliances are rarely moved, and neutral wire failures are extremely rare.  *Not so rare, apparently.*  When you lose neutral on a NEMA 10 connection, it electrifies the chassis of the machine. The washer next to it is properly grounded, touch both and BLAM.

So that 4-prong hookup provided a real safety dividend for you today.

Comment: Why the near-nil reading N-G then? I agree that an open neutral is possible here, but I'd expect the neutral to be floating with regards to ground as well...

Comment: I opened the receptacle and it has NO neutral wire connected. It just had some 10-2 wire coming in with white and black on H1 and H2 and the bare on G. The silver N slot was just tightened down with nothing in it.

When we got out previous dryer 2 years ago, it was a three prong. The hookup at our new house was a 4 prong, so I got a 4 prong pigtail and hooked the dryer up. This new dryer actually requires all four, so that must be why it's not working.

I'm going to just re-run the wire with some 10-3 and see what happens. I'm hoping it works. I've learned a decent bit today. :)

Comment: I ran the new 10-3 wire yesterday and hooked it up in the panel box. Dryer started right up. Thanks for the help!